# Concatenated columns should have the same type (How to convert or cast DateTime to the right type) ML.NET C# SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, ml.net

I want to use a `DateTime` type as feature of my machine learning model.

It generates the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Concatenated columns should have the same type. Column "DateTime" has type of DateTime, but expected column type is Single.

I have the following code:

```
public static IEstimator<ITransformer> BuildTrainingPipeLine(MLContext mLContext)
{
    // Data process configuration with pipeline data transformations 
    var dataProcessPipeline = mLContext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding(outputColumnName: "LatitudeEncoded", inputColumnName:"Latitude")
        .Append(mLContext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding(outputColumnName:"LongitudeEncoded", inputColumnName:"Longitude"))
        .Append(mLContext.Transforms.Concatenate("Features", new[] { "LatitudeEncoded", "LongitudeEncoded", "DateTime", "Temperature", "Unit" }));

    // Set the training algorithm 
    var trainer = mLContext.Regression.Trainers.FastTree(new FastTreeRegressionTrainer.Options()
    {
        NumberOfLeaves = 20,
        MinimumExampleCountPerLeaf = 10,
        NumberOfTrees = 500,
        LearningRate = 0.2822519f,
        Shrinkage = 2.151229f,
        LabelColumnName = "FillLevel",
        FeatureColumnName = "Features"
    });

    var trainingPipeline = dataProcessPipeline.Append(trainer);

    return trainingPipeline;
}
```

The error happens on this line of code:

```
ITransformer model = trainigPipeline.fit(dataView);

public static ITransformer Train(MLContext mLContext, IDataView dataView, IEstimator<ITransformer> trainingPipeline)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Training start");
    ITransformer model = trainingPipeline.Fit(dataView);
    Console.WriteLine("Training done");
    return model;
}
```

My main method looks like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var mLContext = new MLContext();
    var loader = mLContext.Data.CreateDatabaseLoader<Message>();
    var connectionString = GetDbConnection();

    var sqlCommand = "SELECT CAST(MessageId as REAL) as MessageId, CAST(DateTime as string) as DateTime, CAST(FillLevel as REAL) as FillLevel, " +
        "CAST(Temperature as REAL) as Temperature, CAST(Latitude as REAL) as Latitude, CAST(Longitude as REAL) as Longitude, " +
        "CAST(MessageType as REAL) as MessageType, CAST(Unit as REAL) as Unit from Test WHERE Unit = 1";

    var dbSource = new DatabaseSource(SqlClientFactory.Instance, connectionString, sqlCommand);
    Console.WriteLine("Loading data from database");
    IDataView data = loader.Load(dbSource);
    var set = mLContext.Data.TrainTestSplit(data, testFraction: 0.2);
    Console.WriteLine("Preparing training operations");
    var trainingData = set.TrainSet;
    var testData = set.TestSet;
    IEstimator<ITransformer> trainingPipeline = BuildTrainingPipeLine(mLContext);
    ITransformer model = Train(mLContext, trainingData, trainingPipeline);
    Evaluate(mLContext, model, testData, trainingPipeline);
}
```

The `GetDbConnection()` function:

```
private static string GetDbConnection()
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
    return builder.Build().GetConnectionString("DbConnection");
}
```

My message class looks like this:

```
public class Message
{
    [ColumnName("MessageId"), LoadColumn(0)]
    public float Messageid;

    [ColumnName("DateTime"), LoadColumn(1)]
    public DateTime DateTime;

    [ColumnName("FillLevel"), LoadColumn(2)]
    public float FillLevel;

    [ColumnName("Temperature"), LoadColumn(3)]
    public float Temperature;

    [ColumnName("Latitude"), LoadColumn(4)]
    public float Latitude;

    [ColumnName("Longitude"), LoadColumn(5)]
    public float Longitude;

    [ColumnName("MessageType"), LoadColumn(6)]
    public float MessageType;

    [ColumnName("Unit"), LoadColumn(7)]
    public float Unit;
}
```

Comment: Fix the bugs instead of trying to cover them up. Dates are neither strings nor numbers. The SQL query is wrong because it tries to convert the date to a string. The attempts to cast the other fields are a *very strong smell* - either the casts aren't needed, or the numbers are stored as text, a serious error. What is `100,000`? In most the world it's 100. In China, India and the US it's 100K. In Canada it's both

Comment: Besides, where is this error thrown? Are you trying to merge datasets with *different* types? Perhaps loading data from Excel incorrectly? The *right* type when dealing with dates is DateTime, not `Single`. Excel stores dates as floats though. Many libraries will read that as a proper DateTime, but some don't

Comment: *Why* of all datatypes, are you converting almost all of your columns to a `real`? `real` is an imprecise data type, and converting all those columns to `real` is almost definitely going to result in data loss. As for `CAST(DateTime as string) as DateTime`, `string` isn't a data type in SQL Server, so I *assume* this is a user defined data type; ideally you should be prefixing the data type with the schema then (i.e. `dbo.string`).

Comment: You can probably convert the type with a transform - [`context.Transforms.Conversion.ConvertType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.conversionsextensionscatalog.converttype?view=ml-dotnet)

Comment: @JJNL77 Glad it helped!

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It was needed for my machine learning algorithm

Answer (score 0):

You can use CustomMappingFunctions or General Conversions to solve this:

Add the custom output to your ModelInput:

```
public class Message
{
    [ColumnName("MessageId"), LoadColumn(0)]
    public float Messageid;

    [ColumnName("DateTime"), LoadColumn(1)]
    public DateTime DateTime;

    [ColumnName("FillLevel"), LoadColumn(2)]
    public float FillLevel;

    [ColumnName("Temperature"), LoadColumn(3)]
    public float Temperature;

    [ColumnName("Latitude"), LoadColumn(4)]
    public float Latitude;

    [ColumnName("Longitude"), LoadColumn(5)]
    public float Longitude;

    [ColumnName("MessageType"), LoadColumn(6)]
    public float MessageType;

    [ColumnName("Unit"), LoadColumn(7)]
    public float Unit;
}

public class CustomMappingOutput
{
    [ColumnName("CustomMappingOutput")]
    public float CustomDateHour { get; set; }
}
```

Create the Custom Mapping:

```
    [CustomMappingFactoryAttribute("CustomDateMapping")]
    private class CustomDate : CustomMappingFactory<ModelInput, CustomMappingOutput>
    {
        public static void CustomAction(ModelInput input, CustomMappingOutput
            output)
        {
            var customDate = Convert.ToDateTime(input.Date);
            output.CustomDateHour = (float)customDate.Hour;
        }

        public override Action<ModelInput, CustomMappingOutput> GetMapping()
            => CustomAction;
    }
```

Add it to the pipeline:

```
    var dataProcessPipeline =
        _mlContext.Transforms.CustomMapping(new CustomDate().GetMapping(),"CustomDateMapping")
            .Append(_mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate("Features",
                "CustomMappingOutput",
                nameof(ModelInput.CO2)))
            .AppendCacheCheckpoint(_mlContext);
```

Look here: [MlNetcookBook](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/blob/main/docs/code/MlNetCookBook.md#how-can-i-define-my-own-transformation-of-data)

General conversion:

```
_mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.ConvertType(nameof(ModelInput.date),outputKind:DataKind.Single)
```

[TransformExtensionsCatalog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.transformextensionscatalog.concatenate?view=ml-dotnet)